# How can I get tag badge progress to show up on my profile?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, tag-badges, badge-progress

On Stack Overflow, the reputation section under my Profile -> Activity shows my progress towards my next tag badge.

[image: Stack Overflow]

But on Retrocomputing, this section is blank (since I just hit 5k to earn my last privilege):

[image: Retrocomputing]

What is the criteria to show tag badge progress in this section?

Comment: Congratulations on hitting 5k!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The criteria is that the tag needs to be eligible for badges.  According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/268944), a tag needs to be used on at least 100 questions in order for tag badges to be granted.  Our most popular tag, [hardware](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), has been used 73 times.

Comment: Ah of course.  I figured there was a meta SE post about this, I just couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Comment: And now we have 100 questions in the hardware tag, the badge progress is showing up.